# What is the meaning of $\frac{(Ay,x)}{(y,x)}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inner-products

$x^TAy$ is the inner product of a matrix A.

If x,y are unit vectors, then what is the meaning of $\frac{x^TAy}{x^Ty}$?

What does it do to the inner product?

The orthogonal component of y wrt x is

$y_1=y-\frac{(y,x)}{x,x} x$,

so here $\frac{(y,x)}{(x,x)}$ $x$ represents the component parallel to $x$.

Similarly is there any relevance for $\frac{(Ay,x)}{(y,x)}$?

Comment: I’ve seen you post a number of questions related to this quantity. It might be helpful or instructive if you gave some context as to why this particular quantity is relevant to you. I’m also just curious!

Comment: @SantanaAfton My system has a state matrix, $A=B^{-1}L$, where L is a Laplacian matrix of an undirected graph. So $Ae=\lambda e$ where e is the eigenvector of A. so $B^{-1}Le=\lambda e$ and $Le=\lambda Be$.

$\sigma$ is the eigenvalue and f is the eigenvector of L.
Then $f^TLe=f^T \lambda B e \implies \lambda=\frac{f^TLe}{f^TBe}$.
So $\lambda= \frac{\sigma f^Te}{f^TBe}$.

I observe that this quantity $\frac{f^Te}{f^TBe}$ is equal to $\frac{g^Te}{g^TBe}$, where g is the eigenvector of B. Also it was eqaul to $\frac{e^Te}{e^TBe}$.

I am looking for a justification for this.